# Mongoid relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, orm, mongoid

I have article,

```
class Article
  include Mongoid::Document
```

article have category.

```
class Category
  include Mongoid::Document
```

What type of relation I must to use: embedded or referenced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `has_many` and `belongs_to`:

```
class Article
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :category
end

class Category
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :articles
end
```

This relation will be not embedded, so other articles can also be referenced to the same categories. The records of each class will be stored in separate collections (articles and categories).